# vscode java: Add source folder ignored

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

I'm getting this message from `vscode`:

> MockServerConfiguration.java is not on the classpath of project hes-mpi-hazelcast-loader-service, only syntax errors are reported

I've created a profile into my `pom.xml`:

```xml
<profile>
    <id>mock</id>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- Mock-Server -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mock-server</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockserver-netty</artifactId>
            <version>3.10.8</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>add-source</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <sources>
                                <source>src/main/mock-java</source>
                            </sources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>add-resource</id>
                        <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>add-resource</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <resources>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>src/main/mock-resources</directory>
                                </resource>
                            </resources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</profile>
```

Here my folder project structure:

```
├── src
│   └── main
│       ├── java
│       ├── mock-java
│       ├── mock-resources
│       └── resources
```

I've added `src/main/mock-java` into java source paths and I've also added `mock` profile:

```json
{
    "java.configuration.updateBuildConfiguration": "automatic",
    "maven.executable.options": "-Pmock",
    "java.project.sourcePaths": [
        "src/main/mock-java"
    ]
}
```

However, vscode istelisense seems to ignore tabove configuration.

I mean, when I miswritting something it's not suggesting me compilation errors...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Open the project `hes-mpi-hazelcast-loader-service` as root, after **cleaning Java Language Server Workspace**, right click the folder which contains `MockServerConfiguration.java` and add it to Source Path, then reload window.

If it doesn't work, please share the project in github if convenient for me to reproduce your question.